# Многомерный массив, $_SESSION и вывод foreach

Tags: php, массивы, сессия, foreach

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Заполняю массив следующим образом и записываю его в переменную $_SESSION:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$cnt; $i++) {

$ins1['name'] = $modx->db->escape($_REQUEST['item_name_'.$i]);
$ins1['count'] = intval($_REQUEST['item_quantity_'.$i]);
$ins1['size'] = $modx->db->escape($phi['size']);
$ins1['articul'] = $modx->db->escape($phi['articul']);
$ins1['price'] = $modx->db->escape($_REQUEST['item_price_'.$i]);


$itemAr['item_'.$i] = array (
                "name" => $ins1['name'],
                "item id" => $ins1['articul'],
                "size" => $ins1['size'],
                "price" => $ins1['price'],
                "count" => $ins1['count']
            );
 }
for ($i=1; $i<=$cnt; $i++) {
        $_SESSION['item_info'] = $itemAr['item_'.$i];
}
```

Вывожу следующим образом:

```
    <?php
session_start();
     echo "<pre>";

    foreach ($_SESSION['item_info'] as $item => $itemAr) {
        foreach($itemAr as $attr => $value) {
    echo "[$item][$attr] = [$value]";
        }
}
    echo "</br>";
    print_r($_SESSION['userid']);
    echo "</br>";
    print_r($_SESSION['orderId']);

     echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Выводит ошибку:

> Error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Понимаю, что где-то не так построила цикл, но не совсем понимаю как поправить. Пробовала по разному. Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить цикл или указать на ошибки, если где допустила.

Comment: $_SESSION['item_info'] = $itemAr['item_'.$i]; Вы тут перзаписываете каждое значением новыйм. В итоге у вас там только одно значение, а не многомерный массив. Поставьте $_SESSION['item_info'][]=$itemAr['item_'.$i];

Comment: А на какую строчку он выводит error ? на первый foreach или на второй ? сделайте перед циклами print_r($_SESSION); и посмотрите есть и вообще данные

Comment: И где у вас заканчивается в первом блоке самый первый for???

Comment: Извините, код поправила. Потеряла скобочку. Щас попробую предложенные варианты

Comment: Ругает второй foreach

Comment: Сделайте `print_r();` фашего массива и покажите. да и сами помотрите

Comment: Array][count] = [count5]Array ( [item_info] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => name5 [item id] => articul5 [size] => size5 [price] => price5 [count] => count5 ) ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас во втором цикле перезаписывается значение.

Можно не много упростить код.

```
<?php
//Запись в сессию
session_start();
$cnt = 20;

$result = array();

for ($i=1; $i<=$cnt; $i++) {

    $result[] = array (
        "name" => $modx->db->escape($_REQUEST['item_name_'.$i]),
        "item id" => intval($_REQUEST['item_quantity_'.$i]),
        "size" => $modx->db->escape($phi['size']),
        "price" => $modx->db->escape($phi['articul']),
        "count" => $modx->db->escape($_REQUEST['item_price_'.$i])
        );
}

$_SESSION['item_info'] = $result;
?>


<?php
//Чтение
session_start();
echo "<pre>";

foreach ($_SESSION['item_info'] as $item => $itemAr) {
    foreach($itemAr as $attr => $value) {
        echo "[$item][$attr] = [$value]\n";
    }
}
echo "</br>";
print_r($_SESSION['userid']);
echo "</br>";
print_r($_SESSION['orderId']);

echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\sites\www\mysite.ru\index.php on line 33 выдает такую ошибку

Comment: Что именно написано в этой строке в файле C:\sites\www\mysite.ru\index.php?